# How to get this type of structure response in json using java(Spring)

Tags: java, json, spring, list

I want to get all the stories and its substories from backlog using java.

```
{ stories :
          [
             code du story : 11245;
             title du story : "title1";
             .....
          ] ,
          [ 
             code du story : 212458,
             title du story : "title2";
             .....
                    substories : [
                                    code: 4583 ; title: ”lib3” …. 
                                 ],
                                 [ 
                                    code: 124584 ; title: ”lib4” 
                                 ], …
          ],
          [
             code du story : 12845;
             title du story : "title5";
             .....
          ] ,
          ....
```

I tryed :

```
List<List<Object>>
```

But it doesn't work for me

How to do like this response structure and return it in json?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make classes to serialize and deserialize objects in java
Use objectmapper to to convert from object to string and vice versa. You can use object mapper in Jackson library.

Code example

```
  Class Stories{
       String code;
       String title;
       List<Stories> subStories;
    }

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   List<Stories> stories =  mapper.readValue(jsonstring, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Stories >>() {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In repository, the method to get this should be retourn List<Stories> ?